# Why it show content only when I type in the input?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

But it show me the old messages only when I type something in the input fields. Why ?

```
            myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                var message = snapshot.val();
                $scope.messages.push({
                    name: message.name,
                    message: ': ' + message.text
                });
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   var message = snapshot.val();
   $scope.messagessent.push({
            namesent: message.name,
            datesent: message.date,
            messagesent: ': ' + message.text
   });
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

this will trigger the digest cycle and update the scope and view.

if the `myDataRef.on('child_added'` is out of angular relhm then the scope and view is not updating because angular does know there is change in the scope. so that we need to tell the angular to run the digest cycle by using `$scope.$apply()`

**OR**

wrap it within `$timeout` as, (dont forget to inject the `$timeout` to the controller)

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   $timeout(function() {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        $scope.messagessent.push({
            namesent: message.name,
            datesent: message.date,
            messagesent: ': ' + message.text
        });    
   });           
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but why I need to do this ? I never used it before.

Comment: yes umm this is because `myDataRef.on('child_added'` this event is happening out of angular knowledge, angular doesn't know about this happens, so that but model is updated without updating the view. if digest cycle is run then angular can detect the changes and update the view, so what we need to do here is trigger the digest cycle manually, using `$scope.$apply()` and `$timeout()`;

Comment: if you using `setTimeout()` in angular and update $scope inside the it doesn't update the view, you need to use `$timeout` this will trigger the digest cycle after updating the models. If you use `setTimeout()` you have to manually run the digest cycle as in your question.

Comment: digest cycle is the process which detects the model changes and update the view, so its guarantee to sync the `model` and the `view`.